# Steering wheel controller 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to do a 3d game with a car interior , and I want my car to move with the help of the steering wheel. I made one in blender 3d , and I want to know what script do I need to use to control the movement ( the steering wheel to rotate when move) of the car . Do I need to use a 2d steering wheel to control this aspect ? can I use the 3d model ? ( The game I want to be FPS)

Comment: You can use the 3d model. The most straightforward way to do this would be to make an input that controls the car, then you just have the same input also control the steering wheel.

Comment: I should add a 3d car into the game? not just the car interior

Comment: You can probably get by just using a `BoxCollider` to handle collisions, so you'd only need as much of a 3d model as the player can see. so that's probably things like the hood, the side view mirrors, and the trunk, and whatever is visible from the inside of the car.

Comment: I want to add rotation to the steering wheel , when I rotate left the car moves left , but if I add the same script to the car it doesn't affect the car ?

Comment: Put the script on the car, make the steering wheel a child of the car object, and add a `public GameObject steeringWheel;` field to the script. Drag the steering wheel object into that variable using the inspector. Then when the script turns the car, have it modify `steeringWheel.transform` too.